# How to make image switch positions

Tags: swift, xcode6

How can I make an image start at a predetermined location on screen, and when tapped, appear at a different location, also predetermined. And when tapped then, return to the original location?

Thanks

PS: Working on Xcode 6 - Swift

Comment: Do you have any code showing your attempt?

Comment: I do, but it's not pasting here in this format like you guys do it.

Comment: If you paste your code I can reformat it for you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an UIImageView, simply change its frame. (Let me know if you're using autolayouts):

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "assetName")
```

then when clicked (you can detect by overlaying a clear button over your image, etc):

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, width, height)
```

etc.

Comment: How do I paste my code here like you did so you guys can see it?

Comment: Just use the back tick around your code or the { code symbol. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Every `UIView` has a `frame` property of type `CGRect` which specifies both its size and position. To change the position of a view, you thus have to modify the `x` and `y` values of the frame's `origin`, the location of the upper-left point of the framing rectangle:

```
let view = UIView()

// Set location and size
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)

// Modify location
view.frame.origin = CGPointMake(newX, newY)
```

Depending on what type your view has, there are different approaches to react to taps on the view. A button, for example, can specify a target function that is called when it's tapped.

Generally speaking, you can attach a `UIGestureRecognzier` (such as a `UITapGestureRecognizer`) to detect gestures the user performed on the given `UIView`. You also need to make sure its `userInteractionEnabled` property is set to `true` so that the interaction can be detected in the first place.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm totally new at this. Should I start by making my image an IBOutlet and also an IBAction? For reference purposes, I'm calling my image showBob.